# How to make left-right transition of overlay image ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I have used the below command to make a left to right transition of overlay image over a video.

> ffmpeg -i Test.mp4 -i transparent.png -filter_complex
>   "overlay=x='if(gte(t,0), -w+(t)*100, 3)':y=450" out.mp4

The overlay image is moving from left to right continuously. I need it to stop at certain point, like a left to right transition. How to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Heh, interesting task. So I think solution is

```
ffmpeg -i 1.ts -i 2.ts -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='if(lte(-w+(t)*100,w/2),-w+(t)*100,w/2)':y=0[out]" -map '[out]' -y out.mp4
```

This filter graph moves second picture from left to right until it reaches half of the screen (w/2). So all you need to modify is w/2 in this expression. The same for some static stop point (100 pixels):

```
ffmpeg -i 1.ts -i 2.ts -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='if(lte(-w+(t)*100,100),-w+(t)*100,100)':y=0[out]" -map '[out]' -y out.mp4
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have posted another question here http://superuser.com/questions/730062/ffmpeg-fade-between-images can you help out?

Comment: The `if` and `lte` expressions can be simplified by `min` / `max` expressions. See my other answer below. (I initially wrote it for another question, moved here so as not to create a duplicate thread.)

Comment: Nice! Which values do I have to negate/reverse if I want it to come from the right side, instead of the left?

Answer (score 9):

#### How to do sliding effects?

Generally, for slide effects, you have to:

- Create a background of a certain color (e.g., black) with the correct size and duration, on which the image will be shown, using the [`color` source](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-pal75bars_002c-pal100bars_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc_002c-testsrc2_002c-yuvtestsrc).
- Read the image with the [`movie` source](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#movie-1)
- Overlay the image on top of the background with the [`overlay` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1)
- Set the coordinates of the overlay according to the current frame number or timestamp

#### Example

Here is an example with an image saved as `image.png` (size: 1920⨉1080, duration of the clip: 15 seconds):

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "\
color=black:d=15:s=1920x1080[background]; \
movie=image.png[overlay]; \
[background][overlay]overlay='W-n:(H-h)/2' \
" output.mp4
```

The image will slide from right to left without stopping:

[image]

Here is an example with the image stopping at the center:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "\
color=black:d=15:s=1920x1080[background]; \
movie=image.png[overlay]; \
[background][overlay]overlay='min(W-n\,0):(H-h)/2' \
" output.mp4
```

[image]

#### How to control the sliding parameters

The position of the overlay at any given time is specified as an option of the `overlay` filter. The position must be given as the coordinates of the top left corner of the image.

The X/Y coordinate pair in the first above example is `W-n` and `(H-h)/2`, where:

- `W` is the background width (1920)
- `n` is the current frame number
- `H` is the background height (1080)
- `h` is the overlay height (1080 here, but could be different)

Therefore, at frame 0, the image will initially be placed at *1920 - 0 = 1920* pixels from the left, so the image will slide in from the right as *n* increases.

Some tips:

- If you want to increase the speed of the sliding image, you have to multiply *n* by a fixed number.
- If you want the image to stop at some point, the `x` expression has to evaluate to `0`, so you may use `min(W-n, 0)`. In this case, even if the frame number is greater than the width, the image will not be moved to a negative x position, but stay at 0.
- If you want to slide the image from left to right or bottom to top, just modify the expressions for the coordinates accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for explaining what do those variables mean. It really helped me.

Comment: that `overlay=max....`