# FFMPEG fade between images

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing

I need to do cross fade transition between two images and followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493797/how-to-fade-two-images-with-ffmpeg) which works perfect for two images.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input0.png -loop 1 -i input1.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3)))'" -t 4 frames_%04d.png
```

My intention is to add another image with this. i.e, I need to create a video with 3 images. I have tried creating a video named "video1.mp4" with 2 images and and "video2.mp4" with 1 image. And passed "video1.mp4" and "video2.mp4" to the command as below. The problem is the video2.mp4 is blending from the start of the video which looks like an overlay. The below is the command I used.

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3)))'" -t 6 fade.mp4
```

Can some one help out with the right command?